# How do I clear the cache in Magento 2 for a single product_id

Tags: php, caching, magento2

I have written a cron job which checks for stock quantity changes that have been made directly in the database and have therefore bypassed the Magento core which would have handled expiring the cache.

I was expecting to be able to use the Object Manager in the following way :

```
public function clearCacheforProduct($productID) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cacheManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager');
    $cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $productID);
}
```

This is currently failing silently when the cron job runs.

Any idea how I can purge the cache of just a single Product ID ?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @bxN5. I managed to get some error logging in there and quickly found out that the namespace for the `cacheManager` was slightly wrong.

The correct code is :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cacheManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface');
$cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $productID);
```

For those people running Varnish with Magento too, it's also necessary to purge the data there as well as the Magento call doesn't appear to do it completely. So I added in a cURL request to complete the specific purge :

```
$varnishurl = "www.domainYouWantToPurge.co.uk";
$varnishcommand = "PURGE";
$productID = '760'; // This is the Magento ProductID of the item you want to purge
$curl = curl_init($varnishurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $varnishcommand);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: catalog_product_'.$productID]);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Make sure you've set your permissions correctly for the purge within the Varnish configuration file.

Comment: You can also check _InvalidateVarnishObserver_ and see how the varnish cache is purged. This class observes the 'clean_cache_by_tags' event (this event is dispatched after every product save invocation)

Comment: I tried this, but this did behave in a way it caused a lag in cache refresh on product page, the page was refreshed after a minute or so, after running $cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $productID);

Answer (score 4):

If you look at `\Magento\InventoryCache\Model\FlushCacheByProductIds` you will see the following method (Magento 2.2.3):

```
/**
 * Clean cache for given product ids.
 *
 * @param array $productIds
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(array $productIds)
{
    if ($productIds) {
        $this->cacheContext->registerEntities($this->productCacheTag, $productIds);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $this->cacheContext]);
    }
}
```

With the blessings of DI, I would opt to use core code where possible rather than using your own.

*KISS, and DRY.*

Answer (score 3):

the best way that i found it is to use this code,

```
$objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productR =      $objectManager ->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $productR->get('product_sku');
$product->cleanCache();
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $product]);
```

Please initialize the objectManager and ProductRepository in your constructor

I am using this way now and it is working like the charm

Comment: This is by far the best way currently. I also would have shown a proper DI.

Answer (score 1):

You can just load the product object and call cleanCache()

First initialize $this->productRepository like that:

```
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
   ...
  )
  {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
  }
```

Then call this in your code:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
$product->cleanCache();
```

Comment: Is this another question, or an answer? If it answers the question at the top of the page, please [edit] it according to [answer] to explain how this answers. If this is a question, please delete this and post it as a comment.